# nodejs pdf-creator-node, output is not working in linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-pdf

Error: write EPIPEenter code here

```
at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:154:25)
at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:3)
at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:784:11)
at Socket._write (net.js:796:8)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
at PDF.PdfExec [as exec] (/data/www/apps/apirest_archivoRegional/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:141:15)
at PDF.PdfToBuffer [as toBuffer] (/data/www/apps/apirest_archivoRegional/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:44:8)
at /data/www/apps/apirest_archivoRegional/controllers/archivCentralController.js:311:30
at /data/www/apps/apirest_archivoRegional/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4826:16
at /data/www/apps/apirest_archivoRegional/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4826:16
at /data/www/apps/apirest_archivoRegional/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
at /data/www/apps/apirest_archivoRegional/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4849:21
at /data/www/apps/apirest_archivoRegional/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4390:11
at /data/www/apps/apirest_archivoRegional/node_modules/kareem/index.js:135:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
```

errno: 'EPIPE',
code: 'EPIPE',
syscall: 'write'
}

Comment: What linux version is it running on? If you do `cat /etc/os-release` what does it say? Most likely it's a missing library.

Comment: NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

Comment: Could be a PhantomJS related issue. I believe html-pdf uses Phantom to then generate the pdf but there are libraries needed for it. Are you running this on a Docker container and what version of node are running?

Comment: node version is v12.16.3, and I'm not using doker

Comment: I worked it locally on windows and then I wanted to move it to production on a linux server, I don't know exactly what I should install there, help

Comment: Yeah there is bound to be some extra libraries, I'm just confirming by doing the exact node version and the near exact centos version with Docker to simulate a real life scenario. Might just need a few minutes to test it.

Comment: Yeah this proving to be harder than expected to get everything setup. I have major hurdles with PhantomJS (which is deprecated) from what I remember now. Can you use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-chrome instead?

Comment: implement html-pdf-chrome but I get the following   Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9222
}

Answer (score 3):

You have to install **libfontconfig** package.

`sudo apt-get install libfontconfig`

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Alpine Linux, the problem is different and the solution could be found at https://gist.github.com/vovimayhem/6437c2f03b654e392ccf3e9903eba6af

Depending on the version of Alpine you are using, a different solution should be used. Read through the entire discussion to find the one that suits you best.